# How to say if a MongoDB document's subfield is an array or object with MongoDB C# driver?

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to read a field from MongoDB document where it can be an object with a single value or an array with two values. When it is an array, I wish to read the first element of the array.

[image]

Here are my coding efforts to make a condition to read these values:

```
Value1 = (expando.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == "$Child").Value.GetType().IsArray) ?
expando.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == "$Child").FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == "0").Value.ToString() :
expando.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == "$Child").Value.ToString()
```

expando is where my object is stored.

I've heard that even when the fields are array in MongoDB, in C# they're just gonna be strings. So, my array test won't work.

Comment: I'll just leave this as a comment since it doesn't directly answer your question, but I think you'll make your life easier if you make `Child` always been an array, even if it just has a single entry

Comment: @user20042973 unfortunately that's not in my control. I just have to read them as they are.

Comment: For documents like these that are not strongly typed, it makes more sense to read a BsonDocument, figure out the right child type and then map to a class based on type.